# Delete file with a likely name

Tags: command-line, find, rm

I have a folder which contain .srt and .txt files inside `/var/www/myvideo` folder with filename like this:

```
/var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.en.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.en.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.de.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.de.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/asda2.ja.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/asda2.ja.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.en.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.en.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.de.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/dasa22.de.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/asda2.ja.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course1/module1/asda2.ja.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course2/module3/cccaa.end.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course2/module3/vvv.en.srt
   /var/www/myvideo/course2/module3/vvv.ja.txt
   /var/www/myvideo/course2/module3/aaa.ja.srt
   ...
```

the .srt and .txt file will be inside the subfolders of `/var/ww/myvideo`, but i want to delete the file that has `de.txt` `de.srt` `ja.txt` `ja.srt` postfix, how can i achieve this?